# How to synchronize Basecamp and Google Docs automatically?

Tags: google, google-drive, synchronization, basecamp

Is there a way to synchronize Basecamp attachments with Google Docs? Are there any products on market doing this?

Answer (score 3):

http://www.cloudhq.net/

> Do you need to synchronize files between Google Docs, Basecamp, Dropbox or SugarSync?

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recomment use of [cloudHQ](http://cloudHQ.net). Here are step by step instructions on how to setup cloudHQ to synchronize your Basecamp projects with Dropbox: [blog cloudHQ](http://blog.cloudhq.net/post/9960523835/set-it-and-forget-it-real-time-synchronization)

Comment: Are you affiliated with cloudHQ? If so, you should disclose it.